# MVP + RxJava - Put the Schedulers in the Presenter or in the Interactor?

Tags: android, architecture, rx-java, kotlin, mvp

I am developing an Android application with MVP and RxJava. Well, I have a doubt:

When I am creating my presenter and interactor I can put me Schedulers in the presenter, like this:

**Schedulers in the Presenter**

Presenter:

```
 override fun tryLogin(username: String, password: String) {
                mLoginInteractor.login(username, password)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(object : Subscriber<User>(){
        [...]
        }
```

Login Interactor:

```
override fun login(username: String, password: String) =
 mRetrofit.create(ApiClient::class.java).login()
```

Or I can set the Schedulers in the Interactor, like this:

**Schedulers in the Interactor**

Presenter:

```
 override fun tryLogin(username: String, password: String) {
                mLoginInteractor.login(username, password)
                        .subscribe(object : Subscriber<User>(){
        [...]
        }
```

Login Interactor:

```
    override fun login(username: String, password: String) =
     mRetrofit.create(ApiClient::class.java).login()
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

I see that Google advices to set Schedulers in the Interactor. You can see this in this link:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp-rxjava/

But many people put the code in the Presenter, like this example:

https://github.com/BoydHogerheijde/Android-MVP-example/blob/master/app/src/main/java/nl/bhogerheijde/example/rxmvp/interactor/Interactor.java

So, **Do I set Schedulers in the Presenter or in the Interactor**?

(I think it's a better idea to put in the Presenter as the Intractor job is only to get the Data, but maybe I am wrong...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have good composability, I would recommend that you specify your schedulers as late as possible (unless necessary); this usually means right before subscribing. This way you can reuse f.e. `login()` in another flow without having to thread-hop all the time.

However, this is like, just my opinion...

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to unit test the presenter you should probably put the scheduler in the interactor, because the `subscribeOn()` one is (most of the time) android related (because of the main thread scheduler) and you won't be able to test your presenter (unless you mock the schedulers) if it has android specific classes inside of it.

Comment: I can create a Scheduler provider and mock it in the Presenter via Depency Injection. You can see a nice example in this repo: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp-rxjava